# OWLAPI set DataProperty strict value on subclass assertion

Tags: java, protege, owl-api

I can use this code to  Create the restricted data range :

```
 public void testDatatypeRestriction() throws OWLException {
        OWLOntologyManager m = create();
        OWLOntology o = m.createOntology(EXAMPLE_IRI);
        // Adults have an age greater than 18.
        OWLDataProperty hasAge = df.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(EXAMPLE_IRI + "hasAge"));
        // Create the restricted data range by applying the facet restriction
        // with a value of 18 to int
        OWLDataRange greaterThan18 = df.getOWLDatatypeRestriction(df.getIntegerOWLDatatype(), OWLFacet.MIN_INCLUSIVE, df
            .getOWLLiteral(18));
        // Now we can use this in our datatype restriction on hasAge
        OWLClassExpression adultDefinition = df.getOWLDataSomeValuesFrom(hasAge, greaterThan18);
        OWLClass adult = df.getOWLClass(IRI.create(EXAMPLE_IRI + "#Adult"));
        OWLSubClassOfAxiom ax = df.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(adult, adultDefinition);
        m.applyChange(new AddAxiom(o, ax));
    }
```

now I need to know how to programmatically define a class as subclass of a dataproperty assertion with strict value :

```
Alex:owlClass
HasAge:DataProperty

Alex HasAge value 35
```

[image]

P.S: both answers are correct.but @ssz answer is more closer answer to the question and it works with both hermit and pellet reasoner.

it seems there is some issue with pellet reasoning on axioms like `hasAge xsd:integer [>=20 , <=20 ]` . see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805384/protege-pellet-deduce-issue)

Comment: A data property states that there is a link between an individual and a value. It cannot be used to state that class is linked to a value.

Comment: The closest you can get to that is to say that your class `Alex` is a subclass of the class `hasAge value 35`, which is what you have in your screenshot.

Comment: Your code does not link an individual to a value. It defines `Adult` as a subclass of the class `hasAge >= 18`.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse you are right. so lets say how to assert programmatically that: `Alex` class is subclass of `HasAge value 35 `?

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse what about [Literal Value Restriction](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Literal_Value_Restriction)?

Comment: @ssz Fair point. I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot appears to show [8.4.3 Literal Value Restriction](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Literal_Value_Restriction), see also [OWL2 Quick Guide, Data Property Restrictions](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-quick-reference/).
Programmatically this looks like following:

```
String EXAMPLE_IRI = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65793751#";

OWLDataFactory df = m.getOWLDataFactory();
OWLDataProperty hasAge = df.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(EXAMPLE_IRI + "hasAge"));
OWLClass adult = df.getOWLClass(IRI.create(EXAMPLE_IRI + "Adult"));

// SubClassOf(:Adult DataHasValue(:hasAge "35"^^xsd:integer))
OWLAxiom ax = df.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(adult, df.getOWLDataHasValue(hasAge, df.getOWLLiteral(35)));
System.out.println(ax);
System.out.println("---------------");

OWLOntology ont = m.createOntology();
ont.add(ax);    
ont.saveOntology(new ManchesterSyntaxDocumentFormat(), System.out);
```

Comment: yes this is more accurate answer. I need to assign hasAge value (35) as an integer not literal. how can I do that?

Comment: In OWL there is no such thing as 'Integer'. Only Literal with some datatype, e.g. with `xsd:int` or `xsd:integer`. 
Just try to play with code and visit links. 
`hasAge value 35` - is a Manchester Syntax string for DataHasValue Restriction, which in functional syntax looks like `DataHasValue(:hasAge "35"^^xsd:integer)`