# protege pellet deduce issue

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

this is my sample ontology created by protege 5.5.2:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#prop -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#prop"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sub1 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sub1">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sup"/>
                    <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#prop"/>
                        <owl:someValuesFrom>
                            <rdfs:Datatype>
                                <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"/>
                                <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                    <rdf:Description>
                                        <xsd:minExclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">12</xsd:minExclusive>
                                    </rdf:Description>
                                </owl:withRestrictions>
                            </rdfs:Datatype>
                        </owl:someValuesFrom>
                    </owl:Restriction>
                </owl:intersectionOf>
            </owl:Class>
        </owl:equivalentClass>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sup"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sub2 -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sub2">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sup"/>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#prop"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom>
                    <rdfs:Datatype>
                        <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"/>
                        <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                            <rdf:Description>
                                <xsd:minInclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">14</xsd:minInclusive>
                            </rdf:Description>
                            <rdf:Description>
                                <xsd:maxInclusive rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">14</xsd:maxInclusive>
                            </rdf:Description>
                        </owl:withRestrictions>
                    </rdfs:Datatype>
                </owl:someValuesFrom>
            </owl:Restriction>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sup -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/amin/ontologies/2021/0/untitled-ontology-33#sup"/>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi -->
```

[image]

[image]

running *pellet* doesn't deduce that *sub2* is subclass of *sub1*,but *hermit* does.

but if define sub2 axiom as `sub2 subclassof : prop value 14`, then pellet can deduce *sub2* as subclass of *sub1* . is there anything wrong with this ontology?

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with Pellet. Try using FACT++ which adheres to the same DL as Pellet and Hermit. There are sometimes slight differences between the reasoners and what exact DL constructs they support (i.e. Hermit supports ID constraints while FACT++ does not). Though in this case I think it is a bug in Pellet.

Comment: Seconded, looks like a bug in Pellet to me. I'd try [=14] instead of >=, <= just to see if it triggers a different behaviour.